# MDX - With Member not working when more than one attribute added

Tags: mdx, cube, olap-cube

I seem to have a problem when I try and add more than one Quarter attribute. The following works no problem.

```
with member [Measures].[myTest] as
([Measures].[sample],
 [Date].[Fiscal Date].[Fiscal Year].&[1415],
 [Date].[Quarter].&[Jul-Sep]
 ),
format_string='$#,###,###,##0'
SELECT NON EMPTY 
{...
```

Now when I try and add one more quarter as a set I get:

VALUE   #Error The  function expects a string or numeric expression for the  argument. A tuple set expression was used.

FORMATTED_VALUE #Error The  function expects a string or numeric expression for the  argument. A tuple set expression was used.

This is how I’m doing the [Date].[Quarter] set.

```
with member [Measures].[myTest] as
([Measures].[sample],
 [Date].[Fiscal Date].[Fiscal Year].&[1415],
 {[Date].[Quarter].&[Jul-Sep], [Date].[Quartr].&[Oct-Dec]}
 ),
format_string='$#,###,###,##0'
SELECT NON EMPTY 
{...
```

Can I have more than one [Date].[Quarter] attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a typo John: `[Date].[Quartr].&[Oct-Dec]`

Try aggregating the two quarters before creating your new measure:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Date].[Quarter].&[Jul-Dec] AS 
    Aggregate(
       {[Date].[Quarter].&[Jul-Sep]
       ,[Date].[Quarter].&[Oct-Dec]}
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[myTest] AS 
    (
      [Measures].[sample]
     ,[Date].[Fiscal Date].[Fiscal Year].&[1415]
     ,[Date].[Quarter].&[Jul-Dec]
    ) 
   ,format_string = '$#,###,###,##0' 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY
```

Comment: Sorry yes whytheq should of been more careful with cut and paste [Date].[Quarter] is correct. If I add one more quarter like "[Date].[Quarter].&[Jan-Mar]" I seem to get an error "Too many arguments were passed to the 'AGGREGATE' function. The maximum argument count for the function is 2."

Answer (score 0):

Problem is

this is a tuple:

```
(
 [Measures].[sample],
 [Date].[Fiscal Date].[Fiscal Year].&[1415],
 [Date].[Quarter].&[Jul-Sep]
)
```

while this is not a tuple:

```
(
 [Measures].[sample],
 [Date].[Fiscal Date].[Fiscal Year].&[1415],
 {[Date].[Quarter].&[Jul-Sep], [Date].[Quartr].&[Oct-Dec]}
)
```

Consider a tuple as a coordinate on a multidimensional plane. Values from each plane need to be singular.

So while `(1,2,3)` is a valid tuple, `(1,{1,2}, 3)` is an invalid tuple. SSAS is just being lenient on you by not throwing some syntax error here.

What you can do if you wish to add more than one quarter is use the `Aggregate` function as below:

```
Aggregate
         (
            {[Date].[Quarter].&[Jul-Sep], [Date].[Quartr].&[Oct-Dec]} * [Date].[Fiscal Date].[Fiscal Year].&[1415]
            ,
            [Measures].[sample]
         )
```

[This](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa216769%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx) is a good starting point to understand the concept of sets and tuples.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145524.aspx) you can learn about the `Aggregate` function.